Detecting % sign using 3of9 barcode font
Im trying to create a barcode that includes the percentage % symbol. Im using the 3o9 font.
For example %PL. I bookended it with the * symbol. However when I scan it I get {L
Is there some decoding required to scan regular expressions?
EDIT:
Im generating the strings based on an algorithm and save it as csv. I then open it in excel and convert the strings to the barcode font (ina seperate column and resize). I then print them out for use.

Your scanner is configured for the "Full ASCII" variant of Code39, which redefines several of the punctuation marks as prefixes to allow encoding of many more characters than originally included.  To actually send a percent sign in "Full ASCII", you'd have to encode it as /E - but then it would actually scan as /E on any scanner that isn't configured for "Full ASCII".  Is there some particular reason why you chose this rather old, rather large symbology?  A more modern symbology such as Code128 would eliminate this ambiguity in encoding, AND produce a smaller barcode.

Thank You for that information! I actually do need the % to be displayed as I am using the barcode to trigger expression based automation on one of my tools.
I just chose the Code39 after googling. I will try Code128 as per your suggestion. Thank You!

@jasonharper Do i need to straddle * on both ends of my string when i use Code128?

You really need some sort of library to produce Code128, its encoding is rather more complicated than can be expressed by putting *s around the string.

@jasonharper I downloaded the font from https://www.dafont.com/code-128.font. I thought I could just install it and use like Code39. Is that not the case?

At the very least, you'd have to calculate the check character that is a required part of Code128.  The barcode is not going to be scannable at all without that.

Ah I see. I did not know about that.

You don't mention where you create the barcodes, and if you need just the code or need to have them embedded somewhere. If all you need is barcode images the free software "Zint" is a good choice. It has around 60 symbologies and can be fully automated to make both images and vector.   Otherwise  save and get a real barcode library. Using a "font" is only going to frustrate you in the long run.

Thanks @MyICQ, Thats helpful! Im generating the strings based on an algorithm and save it as csv. I then open it in excel and convert the strings to the barcode font (ina  seperate column and resize). I then print them out for use.

@thentangler  as a suggestion: get yourself zint and inkscape plus a small programming language able to handle text.  For the same purpose I did a workflow which created barcodes in SVG, then inserted that SVG into a master SVG page. Finally converted all to PDF. Full page done in seconds. It's simple to set up. Alternatively, use HTML templates.
